# Html Ajax button not doing anything

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

im sure this is something obvious but I cant figure it out

onclick of button retrieveScoreButton my button is simply not doing anything

any help is appreciated, im attempting to append the data to a table but cant even get it to register the clicking of the button so I cant test the function showsccore

```
<button id="addScoreButton">Add score</button>
<button id="retrieveScoreButton">Retrieve all scores</button>
<br>

<div id="Scores">
<ul id="scoresList">
</ul>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#addScoreButton").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: $('form').serialize(),
                    url: '/addScore',
                    success: added,
                    error: showError
                }
            );
        }
    );
});



$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#retrieveScoreButton").click(function () {
            console.log(id);
            $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: "/allScores",
                    success: alert("success"),
                    error: showError
                }
            );
        }
    );
});

function showScores(responseData) {
        $.each(responseData.matches, function (scores) {
                $("#scoresList").append("<li type='square'>" +
                    "Home Team " + matches.Home_Team +
                    "Away Team: " + matches.Away_Team +
                    "Home: " + scores.Home_Score +
                    "Away: " + scores.Away_Score
                );

            }
        );
    }

function showError() {
        alert("failure");
    }


</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: "Simply not doing anything" doesn't really describe what's happening.  Check your browser's debugging tools.  Are there any errors on the browser's console?  When you place breakpoints in your code and debug, what specifically happens?  Are the target button elements found when attaching the click handlers?  Are the click handlers executed?  Are the AJAX requests made?  What are the responses?

Comment: apologies, checking the debugging im getting SCRIPT5009: 'id' is not defined, The AJAX calls work fine, and the addScoreButton is working perfectly, when clicking the retrieveScoreButton its not registering the click and the only error I can locate is the SCRIPT5009: 'id' is not defined

Comment: What are you expecting `console.log(id);` to do?  Where do you think you've defined `id`?  Also, once you correct that, `success: alert("success")` isn't going to do what you think it will.

Comment: So simple, thanks so much David, I had myself convinced it was talking about the id of the button and had myself running in circles, works a charm, kicking myself, I had stuck alert ("success") in just so I could tell when the button click was being registered

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things wrong here:

```
console.log(id);
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    url: "/allScores",
    success: alert("success"),
    error: showError
});
```

First, you never defined `id`.  (After some comments on the question it turns out your browser console is telling you that.)  What are you trying to log?  You may as well just remove that line entirely.

Second, what are you expecting here?:  `success: alert("success")`  What's going to happen here is the `alert()` is going to execute *immediately* (before the AJAX call is even sent) and then the *result* of the alert (which is `undefined`) is going to be your success handler.  You need a handler function to be invoked after the AJAX response, and *that* function can contain the alert.

Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    url: "/allScores",
    success: function() { alert("success"); },
    error: showError
});
```

(To illustrate the difference, compare your current success handler with your current error handler.  One of them invokes the function with parentheses, the other does not.  You don't want to invoke a handler function right away, you want to set it as the handler to be invoked later if/when that event occurs.)